# Parameterized SQL and NULL running slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-profiler

I'm calling some parametrized sql from .net. I'm not sure why but the sql runs quite slow when checking if the parameter is NULL compared to when its not included:

So this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
 SELECT [id]
 FROM [tblAddress] (nolock)
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND ([id] = @id OR @id  IS NULL)

',N'@id int',
@id=4395
```

Runs quicker then this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
 SELECT [id]
 FROM [tblAddress] (nolock)
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND ([id] = @id)

',N'@id int',
@id=4395
```

Running SQL profiler the duration of the top query over 1 million rows is 175 and its reads are 3720 but the second query's duration is 1 and only 3 reads.

Why such a difference and how could it be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An OR clause isn't SARGABLE so the plan used has a scan, not a seek like the 2nd one

Try this: 2 seeks

```
SELECT [id]
 FROM [tblAddress]
 WHERE [id] = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT [id]
 FROM [tblAddress] 
 WHERE @id IS NULL)
```

Note: you don't need the NOLOCK hint. Or `1=1`

Comment: That is way quicker, thanks. I don't understand why it would scan given the `@id  IS NULL` statement does not need the table?

Comment: Also how does the `1=1` speed it up? And does it always scan when an OR statement is used regardless of what is being evaluated?

Comment: 1=1 is only for dnycmic SQL so I assumed you wanted it. It isn't needed. @ID is still a parameter so needs included in the plan for when it isn't NULL. But why are you using sp_executesql anyway...?

Comment: @g.foley: As a side note: ADO.NET does not necessarely use sp_executeSql - it may just look like it does in SQL Profiler (instead it may use a special RPC call of the TDS protocl). More info here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/02/18/Why-Parameters-are-a-Best-Practice.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can make it to SEEK if @id is NULL, so it will always SCAN, and will always be slow (depending on the amount of rows in [tblAddress]. To fight this, you might want to limit the amount of results, returned by your query by specifying the TOP(N) clause.

So what I would do is:

```
IF @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT [id]
      FROM [tblAddress]
     WHERE [id] = @id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(20) [id] FROM [tblAddress] 
END
```

Also, I wouldn't use the NOLOCK hint if it is not strictly reuired.