# How to avoid one condition if i pass a variable value null

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is if i pass value in a variable it should has to check the conditions if i pass a null value in variable it should not consider the condition.please help me..

ex:if i pass firstdateofservice variable as null it should not check the condition

```
DECLARE @FirstDateofService DATE;
DECLARE @LastDateofService DATE; 

SET @FirstDateofService= '04/01/14'; --mm/dd/yyyy
SET @FirstDateofService= CONVERT(varchar(10),@FirstDateofService,21)
SET @ProcessDate  = '10/31/14'; --mm/dd/yyyy 
SET @ProcessDate=CONVERT(varchar(10),@ProcessDate,21)


SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
           AND cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice
           and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
```

Comment: you can check if condition to fire a query

Answer (score 1):

You can add this condition:

```
  ...
   WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
         AND (cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice
            OR @firstdateofservice IS NULL)
       and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
```

OR add check like this:

```
SET @FirstDateofService = ISNULL(@FirstDateofService, '19000101')

SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
           AND cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice
           and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
```

Comment: I would go for the second one, reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468032/parameterized-sql-and-null-running-slow

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the null check in the condition like so:

```
WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
       AND (@firstdateofservice IS NULL OR cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice)
       and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add the `null` condition here like

```
SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
           AND 
 (cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice  or  isnull(@firstdateofservice , '') = '')
 and (cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice or isnull(@firstdateofservice , '') = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?.

```
DECLARE @FirstDateofService DATE;
DECLARE @LastDateofService DATE; 

SET @FirstDateofService= '04/01/14'; --mm/dd/yyyy
SET @FirstDateofService= CONVERT(varchar(10),@FirstDateofService,21)
SET @ProcessDate  = '10/31/14'; --mm/dd/yyyy 
SET @ProcessDate=CONVERT(varchar(10),@ProcessDate,21)

IF @FirstDateofService IS NULL
SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
           and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) 
           AND cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice
           and cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice
```

Comment: yes but i have a lot of variables like that how can i minimize the query

Comment: you have to go for dynamic query, assign the select statement without where condition to a string variable and based on the parameter value add them. finally execute the string variable.

Comment: can you please show with some example by taking two variables please i am new with this concept..Thanks in advance for replying

Comment: DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(300)

Comment: `DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(300)
SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE'
IF @Cisid IS NOT NULL 
SET @sql = @sql + ' cisid IN (' + cast(@Cisid as varchar(10)) + ')'
EXEC(@sql)`

Comment: Thank you so much ps_prakash02

Answer (score -1):

you can change your `WHERE` in this format `(column = @filter OR @filter IS NULL) AND (column2 = @filter2 OR @filter2 IS NULL)`

Something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cs.* 
    FROM   claimline cl(nolock) 
           JOIN claimsummary cs(nolock) 
             ON cs.claimsummaryuid = cl.claimsummaryuid 
    WHERE  (cisid IN(@Cisid,@cisid1) OR (@Cisid IS NULL AND @cisid1 IS NULL ) )
           AND (cs.firstdateofservice  >=@firstdateofservice OR @firstdateofservice IS NULL)
           and (cs.lastdateofservice>=@lastdateofservice OR @lastdateofservice IS NULL)
```